# Where can I save command prompt customizations in windows 10 22H2

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

I want to have different title and prompt in my cmd, but cannot make it permanent. If I get it correct HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor autorun string method is not valid anymore. What is new method?

Comment: What new method?  Windows 11 is not much customizable.

Comment: too bad. the only customization you can do is by right clicking the title bar of the CMD and changing those stuff. Although there should be a registry entry that stores the values, as for the font color, the key called `DefaultColor` stores the font and terminal background color. I doubt there is a registry value for this, as I searched the whole internet and found nothing. I would also like having a feature like that... anyone else have a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor`
no longer exists in Windows 11.

However, you may still create it and it still works:

- Run regedit
- Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft`
- Right-click `Microsoft` and select *New > Key*
- Enter the key name as `Command Processor`
- Click on "Command Processor"
- On the right pane, right-click and select *New > String*
- Name the item `autorun`
- Double-click it and set its value to the command to run
- Click OK and it's done.

It's unknown for how long this will work, but for the moment it
works the same as in Windows 10.